# ubuntu 18.04.1 copper ethernet is now wlp2s0 - no wifi interface available - eno1 just sits there

Tags: networking, wireless, ethernet, iwlwifi

Dell Latitude  E6430 - ive not fooled around with things so this is an update thats got this confused.  I now have copper wired ethernet connectivity, somehow via my wlp2s0 interface instead of the eno1 interface which sits there doing nothing.  Wifi scan sees no wireless networks.  But when Im out I have to have wifi so im stuck here.

software update doesnt show any drivers to be updated.

```
$ dmesg | grep -i wlan
[   17.081015] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0 wlp2s0: renamed from wlan0

$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list
00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection [8086:1502] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Dell 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection (Lewisville) [1028:0534]
    Kernel driver in use: e1000e
    Kernel modules: e1000e
00:1a.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 [8086:1e2d] (rev 04)
--
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Ultimate-N 6300 [8086:422b] (rev 35)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Centrino Ultimate-N 6300 3x3 AGN [8086:1121]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi


$ rfkill list
1: dell-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

$ ifconfig -a
eno1: flags=4098<BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether d4:be:d9:75:af:65  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 20  memory 0xf7f00000-f7f20000  

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 315  bytes 29571 (29.5 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 315  bytes 29571 (29.5 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp2s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.59  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.69.255
        ether 3c:a9:f4:41:41:90  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 10993  bytes 13755428 (13.7 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 6905  bytes 849653 (849.6 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

$ sudo lshw -C network
  *-network DISABLED
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 19
       bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
       logical name: eno1
       version: 04
       serial: d4:be:d9:7c:ff:95
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k duplex=full firmware=0.13-3 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:30 memory:f7f00000-f7f1ffff memory:f7f38000-f7f38fff ioport:f060(size=32)
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Centrino Ultimate-N 6300
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlp2s0
       version: 35
       serial: 3c:a9:f4:44:4b:30
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.15.0-36-generic firmware=9.221.4.1 build 25532 ip=192.168.69.59 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:31 memory:f7e00000-f7e01fff
```

Comment: It's a little unclear what your problem is. You say that you have no wireless, yet your wireless interface has an IP address. For ethernet, is a CAT6 cable plugged into the ethernet port? Where does it connect to? Edit your question with the output of `sudo lshw -C network`. Report back to @heynnema

Comment: @heynnema question is updated.  That IP address on there is due to my CAT6 cable being connected to the copper eth port of the laptop. when I scan wifi nets nothing shows up, though the wifi LED on the laptop periodically flashes regardless of what is going on. Not sure why ubuntu has both NICs somehow connected together

Comment: The ethernet shows no link. How/where is the cable connected? To a hub, switch, router, or cable/dsl modem? There appears to be no connection between the wireless and the ethernet. If you disconnect the ethernet, does the wireless start to work?

Comment: ok yes i guess i see it now that my wifi must be connecting to my home network, even though there is no evidence of this in ifconfig or in my xwindows network GUI control panel.  it just says "no networks" (if i disconnect the ethernet cable the laptop stays connected) so really I guess this is a GUI/ubuntu issue

Comment: What version Ubuntu? You also didn't answer my questions about your network wiring configuration.

Comment: @heynnema thanks for helping me here - its ubuntu 18.04.1 and the copper eth cable connects to a switch that is on the same LAN as the wifi.

the netplan config file has the ssid and wpa2 password for my local wifi net so that is how it is figuring out how to connect, but the ubuntu network config gui doesnt show any of that.

I also tried to `ifconfig eno1 up` and it came up but would never DHCP an IP address.  Ill dig out another PC and make sure that switchport is connecting right..

Comment: Why are you using netplan instead of NetworkManager? Edit your question and show me your netplan .yaml file (x out the wireless password).

Comment: actually this is the first time ever I set up a ubuntu desktop, normally they are servers and I completely disable both netplan and/or networkmanager and statically config interfaces (never dealt with wifi either).  in this case though, I also see "Starting Network Manager" log entries in all the `OK` items during boot.  So apparently I have both running.

Comment: anyhow - after you pointing out that my system stuff/interfaces wasnt mixed up after all I went and looked at netplan docs and got config in there to get my copper eth up and running, so I guess there was some big confusion on my part.  Im pretty sure that I never manually configured the netplan with my home wifi - so that had to be done by some ubuntu GUI, but for whatever reason that GUI isnt working now - still no networks found in wireless network settings.

anyhow - things are working now it seems.  thanks much for your direction on getting me to understand this.

Comment: In your .yaml file, are you using networkd or NetworkManager? You should probably be using NetworkManager. Report back to @heynnema

Comment: @heynnema
  renderer: networkd

Comment: Switch out to the NetworkManager sample script, and then use the GUI to configure your adapters. Do you need guidance to do that?

Comment: @heynnema - yea sorry not quite sure what you mean - should I just completely disable netplan?

Comment: You're not using a server, correct? Then there's probably no reason to run netplan, whilst NetworkManager has been used forever, and it allows you to use the GUI to configure your network devices. A lot easier than writing/debugging a .yaml script. You don't disable netplan, you just use a .yaml script that enables NetworkManager.

Comment: ps: see my answer for how to do this easily. Please remember to accept the answer if it was helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend using NetworkManager instead of netplan. Then you can use the normal GUI tools to configure your network devices.

In `terminal`, do the following...

- `cd /etc/netplan` # change directory
- `sudo mv existing.yaml existing.yaml.HOLD` # rename the existing file
- `sudo pico config.yaml` # create a new file

Enter the following text, keeping the same indentation format...

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

- `sudo netplan --debug generate` # generate the config files
- `sudo netplan apply` # apply the new config files
- `reboot` # reboot the computer

Now go to the network settings panels for wired and wi-fi and configure your devices.